# How to use RVM gems with Netbeans in Ruby

Tags: ruby, netbeans, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 . I installed this ruby using RVM, But Now, I want to use Netbeans editor for my "ruby on rails" project. But problem I am facing is this screen is showing *system* ruby version. and Not RVM. It doesn't detect my RVM ruby even I click auto-detect ruby.

**Which Path I should choose for Interpreter, Gem Home , For Gem Path and Gem Tool?**

When I run `vm use 1.9.3` I get output below:

```
 cis@chef:~/Desktop/PowerPlus$ rvm use 1.9.3 

 Using /home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
```

[image]

Comment: The current version of NetBeans no longer supports Ruby. You will have trouble using NetBeans 6.x with modern Ruby and Rails versions. May I suggest [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby)?

Answer (score 1):

The following article, and its comments, might provide some suggestions:

http://www.skorks.com/2010/01/using-multiple-rubies-seamlessly-on-the-one-machine-with-rvm/

Answer (score 0):

the interpreter path would the one which is stored inside ur rvm
`/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p352/bin/ruby`
follow the following commands
1 rvm use 1.9.3
2 which ruby